# 70s sci-fi show about man who could adapt his body at will

Tags: story-identification, tv

I’m trying to remember the title of a short-lived sci-fi TV show in 1970s. The protagonist suffered some accident, I think, that left him with the ability to control his involuntary body functions. For example, he could slow his heartbeat down to mimic death, or hold his breath for long periods of time. I don’t think there were many episodes; it wasn’t a good show.

Comment: Since you did not specify, I assume it was broadcast in the USA? Or was it produced somewhere else? (UK, Australia, etc) as I assume it was in English.

Comment: Yes, sorry, US, in English. I really don’t have any other recollection.

Comment: This sounds like the film [The Pumaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pumaman).

Comment: I do not know the answer. But I remember that in the series "Knight Rider" (and also in the series "The 6 Million Dollar Man") there was one episode featuring such a man who seems to have more background than the usual "one episode side character". It seemed to me in both cases that they "tried out" the character before giving him an own series. Or maybe it were crossover episodes to attract fans of the one series to the other.I remember that at least in 6 Mio. Dollar Man the character had a kind of Mantra like "Om, Shanta, Peace" which helps him to control his body.

Comment: Thanks all, the Bionic Woman episode may be it.

Answer (score 4):

One of the comments nailed it for me. I think I've been trying to remember this myself for years, but their mention of The Six Million Dollar man and, "Om, Shanti, Peace" really set my brain going, and I was able to find it.

[The Bionic Woman, Season 2, Episode 12, Biofeedback](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0526163/?ref_=ttep_ep12)

> Jaime teams up with Darwin Jones, an expert in meditation and
> biofeedback to stop his brother Payton from selling a code analyzer to
> foreign powers. If they get their hands on the analyzer, the
> identities of every OSI agent are at stake.

The [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/TheBionicWoman) page has this episode as a likely spinoff candidate, but it never went anywhere as far as I know. Also I have no idea if there was a related Knight Rider episode, but a few quick searches on the name don't find anything.

Comment: Thanks Jim. That might be it, I need to watch to verify.